# How to continue to playback the last time position when opening a YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I'm watching [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrjFHmh_lTQ&list=PLqIVmFaHA8BqoeUlCNYUncJOyadUKpbkY) and it has tens of clips that I can hardly watch at once.

The problem I have is that the next time I open the playlist, it starts from the clip #1.

How can I get YouTube to return to the last position of one playlist?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/video-resumer/ it also exits for chrome

Comment: What is it, and what does it do? Please add some description to your answer. Otherwise, if the page you're linking to goes away, the answer will be of little use.

Comment: @plopen Vidar is right. Please add summary content about your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This Firefox extension does the job.:

Automatically resumes YouTube videos from where you played them last. Without this extension, for example, when you click through YouTube videos, back and forth, they always start from the beginning. No more. With this extension, previously seen videos will resume from where you left them at. Even if you restart your browser

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/video-resumer/ it also exits for chrome

Seeing as proper didn't add more info, added this to help others.

Comment: Does the opposite plugin exist? For me, videos always start from where I played them last, and I want them to start at the beginning every single time.